# ExecuteStoreCommand can't return string with SqlParameter output

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures

Something really weird today.

When I try to call a stored procedure in SQL Server with the `objectContext` from Entity Framework, using the function `ExecuteStoreCommand`, it always tries to convert to 'string' value to 'int' .. I don't know why.

Even if I set the output as an `NvarChar` type.

My exception is

> Failed converting the varchar value 'text' to int data type

Here is my C# code:

```
public virtual string GetCardCodeLinkedToAttestation(string atBuisnessCode)
{
    // Input param - String
    SqlParameter atBuisnessCodeParameter = new SqlParameter("atBuisnessCode", atBuisnessCode);

    // The output param - String
    SqlParameter retval = new SqlParameter("retval", SqlDbType.NVarChar,15);
    retval.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

    ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreCommand("exec @retval = sp_GetCardCodeLinkedToAttestation @atBuisnessCode", atBuisnessCodeParameter, retval);

    return (string)retval.Value;
}
```

Here is my stored procedure in SQL Server (I explicitly return 'test' for be sure is a string ):

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_GetCardCodeLinkedToAttestation]
    @atBuisnessCode nvarchar(9)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @retval varchar(15);
    set @retval= '';

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    SET @retval = (SELECT TOP 1 [CardCode] 
                   FROM [SC-SAP01].[SWC_PROD].[dbo].[OCPR]  
                   WHERE [U_Attestation] = @atBuisnessCode)

    RETURN 'test';
END
GO
```

Exception :

> Failed converting the varchar value 'text' to int data type

[image]

I tried to set the value without return it, and declare the output in my stored procedure, but the value returned is always NULL.

[image]

Comment: The return type for stored procedures is always `int`. If you want a string, use an `output` parameter or place it in a result set - don't use `return`. Also, you should avoid using `sp_` as a prefix when naming your stored procedures - it's reserved for Microsoft's System Procedures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find, Finally i use (ExecuteStoreQuery) instead of (ExecuteStoreCommand). Where i put my sql directly Inside. And it's return me the string result of my select. Easy . Thank you for try to help me ;-) .

```
public virtual string GetCardCodeLinkedToAttestation(string atBuisnessCode)
    {
        string return_value = ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreQuery<string>
        (string.Format("SELECT TOP 1 [CardCode] FROM [SC-SAP01].[SWC_PROD].[dbo].[OCPR] WHERE [U_Attestation] = '{0}'", atBuisnessCode)).FirstOrDefault();


        return string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(return_value) ? string.Empty : return_value;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Here you need to use Output as return will always return int datatype.

By default, the successful execution of a stored procedure will return `0`

Please try below code:

```
@atBuisnessCode nvarchar(9),
@retval varchar(15) OUTPUT 
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @retval varchar(15);
    set @retval= '';

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    set @retval= (SELECT TOP 1 [CardCode] FROM [SC-SAP01].[SWC_PROD].[dbo].[OCPR]  WHERE [U_Attestation] = @atBuisnessCode)

    --return 'test';
END
GO
```

Comment: The return i'm waiting is a string value like (R_123332) . As i can see, is always return a int ? Even if i declare an output as varchar ?. With your solution, I always get the return value [0]..

Comment: if i set @retval = '1234' , i get correctly a string with1234 . I suppose he try to Parse the result as int. But why ? . Have no solution for return a full string value as an output?

Comment: Are you using "return" statement at the end?

Comment: Hi , thank you take time for me. No i removed totally the 'return'. But now the output always equal to NULL. I add a new screenshot of my storeproc and code c# in the description. Thank you again

Comment: I guess you are missing something in code. please have a look here http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/748619/ADO-NET-How-to-call-a-stored-procedure-with-output

Comment: I don't use SqlConnection  class from System.Data.SqlClient, but ExecuteStoreCommand from ObjectContext for execute a SQL query directly from Entity. But thank you , i will check if i miss Something from your example.

Comment: it must be something from C# code side as your SP looks fine

Comment: I find, Finally i use (ExecuteStoreQuery) instead of (ExecuteStoreCommand). Where i put my sql directly Inside. And it's return me the string result of my select. Easy . Thank you for try to help me ;-) .